# FFMPEG failed to transcode mp4 Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Tags: php, video, drupal, ffmpeg, drupal-7

Hi I tried using ffmpeg to convert a video with Drupal, however it fails on second pass. I get the following error: Any ideas?
I installed the default ffmppeg and libavcodec-extra-53 packages on Ubuntu.

```
 FFmpeg failed to transcode video.mp4.
    Reported errors

    PHPVideoToolkit error: Execute error. It was not possible to encode "/var/www/html/lms2/sites/default/files/videos/original/video.mp4" 
as FFmpeg returned an error. Note, however the error was encountered 
on the second pass of the encoding process and the first pass appear to 
go fine. The error is with the video codec of the input file. FFmpeg 
reports the error to be "Error while opening encoder for output 
stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, 
width or height".
    Executed commands and output

    /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i '/var/www/html/lms2/sites/default/files/videos/original/video.mp4' -vf 'scale=640:360' -strict experimental -vcodec 'h264' -qscale '12' -acodec 'aac' -ac '2' -pass '1' -passlogfile '/tmp/1499411044-595f326449e44-multipass'  -y /tmp/1499411044-595f326449d86.mp4
    ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
      WARNING: library configuration mismatch
      avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
      libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
      libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
      libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
      libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
      libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
      libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
      libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
      libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
      libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/lms2/sites/default/files/videos/original/video.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: isommp42
        creation_time   : 2017-04-28 15:24:27
      Duration: 00:08:21.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 443 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 314 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-04-28 15:24:27
          handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-04-28 15:24:27
          handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
    Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] -qscale is ignored, -crf is recommended.
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] using SAR=1/1
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] profile Main, level 3.0
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0 me=dia subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/1499411044-595f326449d86.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: isommp42
        encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, pass 1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-04-28 15:24:27
          handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
          encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-04-28 15:24:27
          handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
          encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 aac
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=   79 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=      64kB time=00:00:02.87 bitrate= 181.6kbits/s    
    frame=  155 fps=154 q=28.0 size=     156kB time=00:00:05.75 bitrate= 222.2kbits/s    
    frame=  237 fps=158 q=28.0 size=     239kB time=00:00:09.00 bitrate= 217.6kbits/s    
    frame=  315 fps=157 q=28.0 size=     339kB time=00:00:12.23 bitrate= 226.9kbits/s    
    frame=  399 fps=159 q=28.0 size=     409kB time=00:00:15.48 bitrate= 216.4kbits/s    
    frame=  467 fps=155 q=28.0 size=     516kB time=00:00:18.27 bitrate= 231.2kbits/s    
    frame=  530 fps=151 q=28.0 size=     689kB time=00:00:21.06 bitrate= 268.1kbits/s    
    frame=  606 fps=151 q=28.0 size=     786kB time=00:00:23.84 bitrate= 270.2kbits/s    
    frame=  686 fps=152 q=28.0 size=     853kB time=00:00:27.09 bitrate= 257.8kbits/s    
    frame=  765 fps=152 q=28.0 size=     942kB time=00:00:30.34 bitrate= 254.4kbits/s    
    frame=  847 fps=153 q=28.0 size=    1041kB time=00:00:33.59 bitrate= 253.8kbits/s    
    frame=  925 fps=153 q=28.0 size=    1103kB time=00:00:36.85 bitrate= 245.2kbits/s    
    frame= 1003 fps=153 q=28.0 size=    1202kB time=00:00:39.63 bitrate= 248.3kbits/s    
    frame= 1076 fps=153 q=28.0 size=    1267kB time=00:00:42.88 bitrate= 242.0kbits/s    
    frame= 1153 fps=153 q=28.0 size=    1334kB time=00:00:45.67 bitrate= 
    frame= 6790 fps=155 q=28.0 size=    6278kB time=00:04:31.37 bitrate= 189.5kbits/s    
    frame= 6850 fps=155 q=28.0 size=    6284kB time=00:04:33.69 bitrate= 188.1kbits/s    
    frame= 6909 fps=154 q=28.0 size=    6299kB time=00:04:36.01 bitrate= 186.9kbits/s    
    frame= 6964 fps=154 q=28.0 size=    6324kB time=00:04:38.33 bitrate= 186.1kbits/s    
    frame= 7023 fps=154 q=28.0 size=    6340kB time=00:04:40.65 bitrate= 185.1kbits/s    
    frame= 7078 fps=153 q=28.0 size=    6345kB time=00:04:42.98 bitrate= 183.7kbits/s    
    frame= 7132 fps=153 q=28.0 size=    6350kB time=00:04:44.83 bitrate= 182.6kbits/s    
    frame= 7182 fps=152 q=28.0 size=    6383kB time=00:04:47.16 bitrate= 182.1kbits/s    
    frame= 7239 fps=152 q=28.0 size=    6444kB time=00:04:49.15 bitrate= 182.6kbits/s    
    frame= 7295 fps=151 q=28.0 size=    6469kB time=00:04:51.52 bitrate= 181.8kbits/s    
    frame= 7355 fps=151 q=28.0 size=    6481kB time=00:04:53.66 bitrate= 180.8kbits/s    
    frame= 7408 fps=150 q=28.0 size=    6489kB time=00:04:55.98 bitrate= 179.6kbits/s    
    frame= 7459 fps=150 q=28.0 size=    6526kB time=00:04:58.21 bitrate= 179.3kbits/s    
    frame= 7517 fps=150 q=28.0 size=    6533kB time=00:05:00.51 bitrate= 178.1kbits/s    
    frame= 7574 fps=149 q=28.0 size=    6540kB time=00:05:02.88 bitrate= 176.9kbits/s    
    frame= 7634 fps=149 q=28.0 size=    6546kB time=00:05:05.06 bitrate= 175.8kbits/s    
    frame= 7679 fps=148 q=28.0 size=    6550kB time=00:05:06.92 bitrate= 174.8kbits/s    
    frame= 8364 fps=145 q=28.0 size=    6754kB time=00:05:34.43 bitrate= 165.4kbits/s    
    frame= 8425 fps=145 q=28.0 size=    6757kB time=00:05:36.85 bitrate= 164.3kbits/s    
    frame= 9020 fps=142 q=28.0 size=    6856kB time=00:06:00.53 bitrate= 155.8kbits/s    
    frame= 9085 fps=142 q=28.0 size=    6858kB time=00:06:02.85 bitrate= 154.8kbits/s    
    frame= 9142 fps=142 q=28.0 size=    6860kB time=00:06:05.38 bitrate= 153.8kbits/s    
    frame= 9200 fps=142 q=28.0 size=    6886kB time=00:06:07.80 bitrate= 153.4kbits/s    
    frame= 9259 fps=142 q=28.0 size=    6888kB time=00:06:10.24 bitrate= 152.4kbits/s    
    frame= 9318 fps=142 q=28.0 size=    6894kB time=00:06:12.61 bitrate= 151.6kbits/s    
    frame= 9375 fps=141 q=28.0 size=    6916kB time=00:06:14.93 bitrate= 151.1kbits/s    
    frame= 9438 fps=141 q=25.0 size=    6944kB time=00:06:17.25 bitrate= 150.8kbits/s    
    frame= 9499 fps=141 q=28.0 size=    6947kB time=00:06:19.57 bitrate= 149.9kbits/s    
    frame= 9561 fps=141 q=28.0 size=    6950kB time=00:06:22.01 bitrate= 149.0kbits/s    
    frame= 9618 fps=141 q=28.0 size=    6955kB time=00:06:24.63 bitrate= 143.6kbits/s    
    frame=10145 fps=139 q=28.0 size=    7080kB time=00:06:45.58 bitrate= 143.0kbits/s    
    frame=10202 fps=139 q=28.0 size=    7105kB time=00:06:47.90 bitrate= 142.7kbits/s    
    frame=10257 fps=139 q=28.0 size=    7124kB time=00:06:50.20 bitrate= 142.3kbits/s    
    frame=10315 fps=139 q=28.0 size=    7143kB time=00:06:52.52 bitrate= 141.8kbits/s    
    frame=10373 fps=139 q=28.0 size=    7145kB time=00:06:54.87 bitrate= 141.1kbits/s    
    frame=10432 fps=138 q=28.0 size=    7174kB time=00:06:57.03 bitrate= 140.9kbits/s    
    frame=10489 fps=138 q=28.0 size=    7180kB time=00:06:59.35 bitrate= 140.3kbits/s    
    frame=10547 fps=138 q=28.0 size=    7199kB time=00:07:01.55 bitrate= 139.9kbits/s    
    frame=10605 fps=138 q=28.0 size=    7215kB time=00:07:03.85 bitrate= 139.5kbits/s    
    frame=10661 fps=138 q=28.0 size=    7223kB time=00:07:06.01 bitrate= 138.9kbits/s    
    frame=10713 fps=138 q=28.0 size=    7277kB time=00:07:08.33 bitrate= 139.2kbits/s    
    frame=10769 fps=137 q=28.0 size=    7303kB time=00:07:10.66 bitrate= 138.9kbits/s    
    frame=10829 fps=137 q=28.0 size=    7309kB time=00:07:12.98 bitrate= 138.3kbits/s    
    frame=10884 fps=137 q=28.0 size=    7329kB time=00:07:15.14 bitrate= 138.0kbits/s    
    frame=10941 fps=137 q=28.0 size=    7355kB time=00:07:17.39 bitrate= 137.7kbits/s    
    frame=11000 fps=137 q=28.0 size=    7360kB time=00:07:19.48 bitrate= 137.2kbits/s    
    frame=11047 fps=137 q=28.0 size=    7407kB time=00:07:21.80 bitrate= 137.3kbits/s    
    frame=11105 fps=136 q=28.0 size=    7423kB time=00:07:23.66 bitrate= 137.1kbits/s    
    frame=11150 fps=136 q=28.0 size=    7472kB time=00:07:25.91 bitrate= 137.3kbits/s    
    frame=11208 fps=136 q=28.0 size=    7541kB time=00:07:27.84 bitrate= 137.9kbits/s    
    frame=11264 fps=136 q=28.0 size=    7553kB time=00:07:30.16 bitrate= 137.4kbits/s    
    frame=11314 fps=136 q=28.0 size=    7589kB time=00:07:32.02 bitrate= 137.5kbits/s    
    frame=11359 fps=135 q=28.0 size=    7635kB time=00:07:34.34 bitrate= 137.7kbits/s    
    frame=11415 fps=135 q=28.0 size=    7698kB time=00:07:36.20 bitrate= 138.2kbits/s    
    frame=11469 fps=135 q=28.0 size=    7740kB time=00:07:38.52 bitrate= 138.3kbits/s    
    frame=11526 fps=135 q=28.0 size=    7752kB time=00:07:40.84 bitrate= 137.8kbits/s    
    frame=11585 fps=135 q=28.0 size=    7755kB time=00:07:43.16 bitrate= 137.2kbits/s    
    frame=11638 fps=135 q=28.0 size=    7791kB time=00:07:45.28 bitrate= 137.2kbits/s       
    frame=12371 fps=133 q=28.0 size=    8045kB time=00:08:14.60 bitrate= 133.2kbits/s    
    frame=12426 fps=133 q=28.0 size=    8068kB time=00:08:16.60 bitrate= 133.1kbits/s    
    frame=12475 fps=133 q=25.0 size=    8113kB time=00:08:18.88 bitrate= 133.2kbits/s    
    frame=12528 fps=133 q=28.0 size=    8135kB time=00:08:21.01 bitrate= 133.0kbits/s    
    frame=12529 fps=133 q=28.0 Lsize=    8549kB time=00:08:21.17 bitrate= 139.7kbits/s
    video:3859kB audio:4279kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 5.047608%
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] frame I:52    Avg QP:14.60  size: 25036
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] frame P:3390  Avg QP:16.73  size:   657
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] frame B:9087  Avg QP:16.09  size:    47
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] consecutive B-frames:  3.0%  0.7%  0.8% 95.5%
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] mb I  I16..4: 53.8%  0.0% 46.2%
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] mb P  I16..4:  2.6%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  2.9%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:94.5%
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.5%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:99.3%  L0:44.8% L1:51.9% BI: 3.3%
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 40.1% 21.9% 16.0% inter: 0.4% 0.4% 0.1%
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] i16 v,h,dc,p: 42% 53%  3%  1%
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 45% 11%  5%  3%  2%  4%  2%  5%
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] i8c dc,h,v,p: 68% 25%  6%  1%
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.4% UV:0.3%
    [libx264 @ 0x1c89940] kb/s:63.07
    /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i '/var/www/html/lms2/sites/default/files/videos/original/video.mp4' -vf 'scale=640:360' -strict experimental -vcodec 'h264' -qscale '12' -acodec 'aac' -ac '2' -pass '2' -passlogfile '/tmp/1499411044-595f326449e44-multipass'  -y /tmp/1499411044-595f326449d86.mp4
    ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
      WARNING: library configuration mismatch
      avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
      libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
      libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
      libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
      libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
      libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
      libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
      libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
      libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
      libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/lms2/sites/default/files/videos/original/video.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: isommp42
        creation_time   : 2017-04-28 15:24:27
      Duration: 00:08:21.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 443 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 314 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-04-28 15:24:27
          handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-04-28 15:24:27
          handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
    Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous
    [libx264 @ 0x1c2b940] -qscale is ignored, -crf is recommended.
    [libx264 @ 0x1c2b940] using SAR=1/1
    [libx264 @ 0x1c2b940] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
    [libx264 @ 0x1c2b940] constant rate-factor is incompatible with 2pass.
    Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/1499411044-595f326449d86.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: isommp42
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0, 25 fps (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-04-28 15:24:27
          handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
          encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-04-28 15:24:27
          handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
          encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 aac
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qscale` is ignored by libx264, so it defaults to CRF mode, except as the message in the log says, `constant rate-factor is incompatible with 2pass`.

Remove `-qscale 12` and add `-b:v 1000k` or whatever your required bitrate is.

If you don't have a number in mind, remove `-qscale 12`, add `-crf 25` and skip the second pass. Experiment with the CRF value for better quality or smaller files.